# Bash completion - How to get filename completion for suboptions

Tags: bash, filenames, autocomplete, arguments

I have a function which can take main arguments and then sub-arguments. Some of these sub-arguments are filenames. The current completion code I have is as follows.

```
_scm() {
    local cur prev opts
    COMPREPLY=()
    cur="${COMP_WORDS[COMP_CWORD]}"
    prev="${COMP_WORDS[COMP_CWORD-1]}"
    opts=$(mpv -input cmdlist | awk '{print $1}')

    case "${prev}" in
        sub_add)
            COMPREPLY=( $(compgen -f ${cur}) )
            return 0
            ;;
        *)
            ;;
    esac

    COMPREPLY=( $(compgen -W "${opts}" -- ${cur} ) )
}
complete -o plusdirs -F _scm scm
```

I want the `sub_add` arg to take a filename as subarg and the current code is able to do that. But, I also want to get autocompletion of args again, once `sub_add` and it's aubargs are completed. But instead file completion keeps happening again and again.

For eg, right now, pressing

```
scm sub_add <TAB>
```

gives me completion for filenames. What I also want is that after completing the filename, the original arg completion should kick in

```
scm sub_add ~/filename.txt <TAB>
```

should give `sub_add sub_load seek....` etc.

The reason for filename completion happening again and again is beacuse of `complete -o plusdirs`. But, without it bash completes both directories and files, while I want only filenames. How can I modify my code to achieve what I want?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there are any builtin or bash-completion standard function to complete only bare filenames.  Directories can contain files so the standard behaviour for completing a filename is to complete on files and directories (as bash-completion's `_filedir` does.  It has an option for only directories, but not for only files.).

You could write a custom function to only return bare filename matches, e.g. iterating on `completions=( "$word"* )` and checking `[[ -f "$i" ]]` to build `COMPREPLY`.

I read your code more carefully.  If you're generating completions for [mpv](http://mpv.io/), you shouldn't restrict it to only working for bare filenames in the current directory.  That's not how any other custom completion function I'm aware of behaves.